# Summernote click event?

Tags: javascript, summernote

How can I handle summernote click event? 
I want to handle cursor position when changing by mouse click. There is a onFocus callback, but when editor already has focus, I can't found a solution.

I want to do something like this:

```
callbacks: {
    onKeydown: function (e) {
        $('#summernote').summernote('editor.saveRange');
    },
    onClick: function (e) {
        $('#summernote').summernote('editor.saveRange');
    }
```

Comment: Please provide code here. and tell us where is the issue?

Comment: I added an example above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've came with this solution:

```
$scope.summernoteOptions = {
    onInit: function () {
        $(".note-editable").on('click', '.cssTargetClass', function (e) {});
            }
        }
    };
```

Where **cssTargetClass** is the class of the type of elements that I want to bind to event.

Answer (score 2):

It's worked for me:

```js
$('#summernote').summernote({

    callbacks: {
        onInit: function() {
            $(".note-editable").on('click', function (e) {
                console.log('clicked');
            });
        }
    }

});
```